# how to repeat a table n number of times based on the number given by the end user?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to repeat a `<table>` a certain number of times (amount supplied by the end user). How can it be implemented ?

Here is the table:

```
External Sources of funds:<input type="text" size="10">
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Name of the external Source</th>
        <th>CFY</th>
        <th>CFYm1</th>
        <th>CFYm2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>    
    </tr>
</table>
</p>`
```

In the first line of code, i.e. External source of funds, the user give the input as some number `n`. The table has to be repeated `n` times. How can I implement it?

Comment: How do you know when to display the tables?

Comment: is it really necessary to display it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intro to for loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    alert("Hello for the " + i + "th time");
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. i was new to this so was confused.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the table 10 times:

```
var i = 0, tableCount = 10;
var html = '<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Name of the external Source</th>
        <th>CFY</th>
        <th>CFYm1</th>
        <th>CFYm2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><b>Total</b></td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>
        <td> <input type="text" size="10"> </td>    
    </tr>
</table>';

for(i; i < tableCount; i++){
    $('body').append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a `event handler` to the textbox.

```
<input type="text" size="10" onkeypress="updateTables();">
```

When user enters something in the textbox, the JavaScript function will be called. Inside the function, you will have to use a `loop` to add the table elements.